# milli/micro second resolution for ITime

Tags: r, time-series, data.table

I am trying to use more extensively [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) and `ITime` is the UDT replicating POSIXlt "DateTime" type.

```
> strptime("01-04-2012 09:23:45.987364", format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%OS")
[1] "2012-04-01 09:23:45.987364"
> time = strptime("01-04-2012 09:23:45.987364", format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%OS")
> class(time)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

But I can't get ms or micro with ITime

```
> time = as.ITime("09:23:45.987364", format="%H:%M:%OS")
> time
[1] "09:23:45"
```

How can I handle fractions with ITime ?
Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems impossible.

```
IDateTime {data.table}  R Documentation
Integer based date class


Details

ITime is a time-of-day class stored as the integer number of seconds in the day. as.ITime does not allow days longer than 24 hours. Because ITime is stored in seconds, you can add it to a POSIXct object, but you should not add it to a Date object.
```

Comment: Correct. Impossible with ITime. Use `POSIXct` for ms or micro. And avoid `POSIXlt` like the plague.